# PowerShell - find a "mysterious" file

Tags: powershell

I have a folder with 67045 files (it should have only 67044).
When I run this script:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include  *.pdf | Group-Object Extension -NoElement
```

I get all 67044 pdf files, exactly how it should be, but I can't get whats that other file.
How can I find it and delete it manually after I confirm that I don't really need that file, or in the worst case, delete everything if it's not PDF.

Comment: Did you try with `-Force` on `Get-ChildItem`?

Comment: Does changing `-Include` to `-Exclude` reveal any other/unknown files then?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - I just tried it and it didn't worked for me.

Comment: So, how do you determine that it has 67045 files (please add that information [to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70448829/edit))

Comment: `-Include` needs an *asterisk* (*wild card*) after the path, or the `-Recurse ` switch.

Comment: No actually it was there with a different name and with a different extension. using -Exclude *.pdf helped me find it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path C:\you\path -Include  *.pdf | Group-Object Extension -NoElement
```

This is giving you the files which are only PDF and the total count of it.

Just alter it to exclude:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path C:\your\path -Exclude  *.pdf -Force | Group-Object Extension -NoElement
```

This will give you all the other file extensions apart from pdf and their corresponding count.

Now the other part of it is as per the requirement, you do not need to group, to figure out what are the other files available other than pdf. Follow the below:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path C:\Scripts\ -Exclude  *.pdf -Force
```

This will give whatever you are looking for, and you can further use Pipe to remove the item like `| Remove-Item -Force`